# send base64 string from android to server with php scripts

Tags: php, android, base64

Hello I am very new to the whole building an app thing.  I need to understand how to send a base64 encoded string from my android app to the server using php. I searched a lot on the web but most of the methods that I found are pretty old now and most of them are even deprecated. I have tried this :

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL(upload_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(userID,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("displayname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(displayName,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("encodestring","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(encode,"UTF-8");
```

here encode string is the base64 string rest are normal strings and 
my php script being something like this :

```
require_once "init.php";
$id=$_POST["id"];    
$originalname=$_POST["displayname"];
$encodedDoc=$_POST["encodestring"];
```

I don't know why it's not accepting the string and is in fact showing HTTP ERROR 500 on the url also.

I even tried sending through json but no luck. I can't figure out what I am missing if anyone has a solution let me know please.